# How to attach a BufferedImage to a MimeBodyPart without creating a File object

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

i'm creating a `BufferedImage` and i'm trying to include it to a `MimeBodyPart`
as follows:

```java
BufferedImage img=generateQR(otp);
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
File test = new File("phill.png");
ImageIO.write(img, "png", test);
DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(test);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
messageBodyPart.setFileName("./phill.png");
messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
test.delete();
```

Is there any way to attach a `BufferedImage` without creating a `File`?

Please assume that

- generateQR() exists
- There is an HTML `MimeBodyPart`

Comment: You can [`write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream)) the image data to any `OutputStream`, e.g. to a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html), and then use the bytes written (to memory) as you like.

Comment: @JimmyB How will the bytes be attached to the `MimeBodyPart`  though? :/

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009587/send-email-with-javax-mail-using-an-existing-inputstream-as-attachment-content

Comment: @PhillAlexakis, maybe use [ByteArrayDataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html) instead of `FileDataSource`?

Comment: @uaraven yes, it worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @JimmyB you are correct , thank you also!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested, you may get the bytes from your image, and use the according datasource.

This is based on the questions :

[Java- Convert bufferedimage to byte[] without writing to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247123/java-convert-bufferedimage-to-byte-without-writing-to-disk)

and

[javamail problem: how to attach file without creating file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556091/javamail-problem-how-to-attach-file-without-creating-file)

You may end up with something like :

```
byte[] imageBytes = ((DataBufferByte) img.getData().getDataBuffer()).getData();

ByteArrayDataSource bds = new ByteArrayDataSource(imageBytes, "image/png"); 
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(bds)); 
messageBodyPart.setFileName("./phill.png");
messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

Edit :

As the databuffer may not always be a `DataBufferByte`, you may put the image data in a byte array that way :

Replace

```
byte[] imageBytes = ((DataBufferByte) img.getData().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

with the following operations :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(img, "png", baos);
baos.flush();
byte[] imageBytes= baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
```

(example inspired from [How I can convert BufferedImage to a byte array without using files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54998070/how-i-can-convert-bufferedimage-to-a-byte-array-without-using-files))

Comment: i think  `img.getData().getBuffer()` returns `DataBufferInt`, and i'm getting a `java.awt.image.DataBufferInt cannot be cast to java.awt.image.DataBufferByte
 at SendEmailSMTP.sendEmail(SendEmailSMTP.java:46)` because of the casting

Comment: `ImageIO.write()` is creating a local png isn't it?

Comment: Not a local file here, it writes to the outputstream you want, in this case it is an in-memory "stream" .

Comment: right i'm sorry i didn't see you were writing to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`

Comment: The first proposed solution will only work if&when the image's data buffer already contains PNG encoded data. This cannot be expected because the image may never have been a PNG before. `ImageIO.write()` is the only reliable way to ensure you get a certain format of image data.